# NHIbernate+MVC+Spring. Dynamic objects (via Activator.CreateInstance) with HibernateTemplate (initialized by Spring) force lazy loading exception

Tags: spring, nhibernate, spring-mvc

The structure of my web-application is the following: 
I have DAO classes (per specific instance) inherited from `BaseDAO<T, TId>`. (Where `T` could be something like "Customers").
The base class contains a `HibernateTemplate` property.

I have a base class for MVC controllers (with inherited ones).

I have a base class for Service (M+V+C+Service model) (with inherited ones per instance (like "CustomersService")).

I have a base class for DAO class (with inherited ones per instance...) (separated in another VS project).

I have POCO object classes (per db table) which mappings (and relations between each other) are defined in an xml file for Hibernate.

An application which is currently working manages all the stuff in the following way (it's functioning as functioning - I've got it as it was implemented before):

- MVC controllers include some service properties (which are necessary for controllers work) and they are initialized by Spring via xml files definitions.
  (eg. `UsersController` can have `UsersService` and `UsersRolesServices` properties)
- Every service includes corresponding DAO-helper property (UsersService has UsersDAO property, for instance), which initialization is defined in xml file as well (for Spring).

So, in general (as every such initialization is defined in the xml file) all that structure is being initialized by Spring at the page lifecicle beginning. And everything works well.
... except of development process convenience
... because I need to define "everything everywhere" in advance, i.e., let's say in case I'd need to have also `UsersWearService` in the `UsersController`, then I have to define its property in the `UsersController` and go to xml file and add its initialization. So that's so unconvenient and unflexible.

**What I was trying to do:**

I've created a method `GetService<UsersService>().GetAllUsers()` (just an example)
which creates the service dynamically via `Activator.CreateInstance` (it allows to call any service in any controller without any pre-definition). Everything was ok except I had no HibernateTemplate (== null) (as it was not "Activated" via Spring). So I tried to get that object via `Application.Current.Context` and `GetObject` to obtain the HibernateTemplate via Spring+Hibernate.

Everything even started working, but only with simple requests.

If I try to do something like this:

```
GetService<UsersService>()
    .GetAllUsers()
    .Where(x => x.UsersEmailsAmount.Count > 0)
```

(when lazy loading of child collections is used)

... it receives the following exception:

> "Failed to lazily initialize a collection - no session or session was closed".

After all that, I even tried to add some property to Controller/Service/Dao (to basic class) (which would need to define only Controller in the xml hibernate file), and I even got the HibernateTemplate property initialized well, but on that lazy loading operation I still have the same exception.

Seems in case of such dynamic loading "something" "somewhere" still has the session reference not initialized (even if I get the HibernateTemplate object via Spring), but I do not know where is that "something" and "somewhere". I feel like all that stuff is going around the POCO objects with some internal behaviour of Hibernate, but can not see how all those things is bound inside of each other.

Can anyone give me at least any clue what's wrong with that, or even if it's theoretically possible to implement what I wanted? (I believe everything possible to do in development, but a question if it worth that time).

I am new with hibernate and guys which were developing this app are ready to spend so much time for all those definitions, but this is so unconvenient and so not obvious (not even saying about new developers (especially without any documentation!))

Comment: All the formatting on this post really makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Seems the devs wanted to use all cool stuff at once in this project.

What you need to investigate is the lifecycle of the nhibernate session.

- When is it opened?
- When is it closed?
- Does spring load the services in one go or per page part call like ajax which thus might influence the session?
- Does object createInstance make your dependencies clearer or are you getting even more stuck in the mud?
- Are there any input- and or output filters, do these open or close, flush the session?

Good luck.

Comment: - as I researched about opening/closing - the session is always seems open. This is the key problem! Because when exploring HibernateTemplate object in debugging, it shows always the same session (the same date creation), and the sesson status is always open.

Comment: - services (and in general, most of objects) are being loaded like singletones, i.e. ones loaded they stay the same.

Comment: - what "Does object createInstance make your dependencies clearer or are you getting even more stuck in the mud?" does mean?

Comment: - I can not see any filters definitions in code. The thing is the application is relatively pretty small and developers which created all those "monsters" are using Spring for the Injection only - and not lots of different HNibernate/Spring features I've heard about.

Comment: Plus, in general I'd not describe all that stuff as "devs wanted to use all cool stuff". I just want to have at least some convenient way for code developing and supporting, since all this "cuisine" with the properties initialization in xml files (and also all properties predefinition in advance) is so far from convenience (at least in common .NET development sense) (and at least as it's implemented in this project - I hope there exist other ways in real life).

Comment: I am sure that other implementations of nhibernate exist IRL, hope that makes you feel better :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some explorations I've discovered that in my "dynamically created DAO" calling for HibernateTemplate.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession() throws the following exception:

**No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here.**

I've read some forums and in some cases they suggest just to defined Transactions management section to config files or to add some attributes for DAO methods like "@Transactional".

But lots of answers are, but they are relatively not to NHibernate (but common Java's one)! So, I still do not have any solvings.

Comment: TransactionManager defined in our config files except this line:
<tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
But after its adding I start receiving another problem with spring:
Error creating context 'spring.root': The parameters and the signature of the method don't match.
even on MVC Controller creation!!!

Answer (score 0):

After some researches I've found out, that the thing I'm trying to do is pretty tricky (at least in my project situation, as I am not allowed to change much).
For any people, who would try to "make my dream true" (in their projects), I can say, that everything possible. The way I see it possible to implement is to write my own SessionContext class (possibly inherited from SpringSessionContext) and to define in current_session_context_class this one to be able to do the following:
 CurrentSessionContext.Bind
(currently that's not possible due to SpringSessionContext limitations).
But in that case it must be defined in NHibernate configuration file outside of Spring.NET infrastructure, which is a pain in the "..."

This is really said to use Spring.NET in our project. I am totally .NET developer and I know C# well, so especially with the last releases of .NET Framework I see less and less reasons to use Spring.NET for MVC Web projects (which is actually confirmed by so few amount of documentation and information on forums (relatively small, of course)).
I believe "xml-defined programming" is far far not for .NET development process (especially with using MS VS + Resharper). I know lots of guys which would say "oh, that's not a problem for me to define all that stuff in xml" and I can understand them, but such approach is not good for big projects, especially for supporting, especially if new people come to development process. I am not a Microsoft fan, but what MS does with .NET is really great and convenient.

**And also, if someone would read these lines, I'd wanted to recommend always to use "NHibernate" as "NHibernate" and "Spring.NET" terms in posts and comments on that, because when you are trying to search in search engines on .NET specificly - this is the same "pain in the ..." to find anything relative.**

Thank you!